# Properly use asynchronous_sink::flush() in Boost.Log

Tags: c++, boost, boost-log

According to the Boost.Log documentation (see the end of [this](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_59_0/libs/log/doc/html/boost/log/sinks/asynchronous_sink.html#idp53818384-bb) page), the `flush()` method of `asynchronous_sink` requires

> The sink frontend must be constructed without spawning a dedicated
>   thread.

This requirement makes no sense to me. Furthermore, it is not met in example code throughout the Boost.Log documentation (e.g., see [here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_59_0/libs/log/example/async_log/main.cpp) and [here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_59_0/libs/log/example/bounded_async_log/main.cpp)). So, how to properly use the `flush()` method exactly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The precondition is incorrect. You can use `flush` when there is a dedicated record feeding thread.

Comment: Really nice to have an answer from the library author himself : )